# Trying to change the value of the element using selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, pycharm

I am trying to change the element using selenium using send keys but it is not changing. I also tried using execute_script, but the value is not changing. i am trying to change to value = R

```
driver.find_element_by_name('wlw-select_key:{actionForm.terminal}').send_keys('R')   

<select name="wlw-select_key:{actionForm.terminal}">
<option value="ALL">ALL</option>
<option value="T">1</option>
<option value="K">2</option>
<option value="B">3</option>
<option value="P">4</option>
<option value="Q">5</option>
<option value="R">6</option>
<option value="V">7</option>
<option value="W">8</option>
<option value="G">9</option></select>
```

Comment: send_keys only works with input html elements...

Answer (score 0):

Use `Select` as given in the documentation http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html

> As you can see, this isn’t the most efficient way of dealing  with SELECT elements. WebDriver’s support classes include one called a “Select”, which provides useful  methods for interacting with these:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('name'))
select.select_by_index(index)
select.select_by_visible_text("text")
select.select_by_value(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do click the select button first then choose the right option from all the options appeared as

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='wlw-select_key {actionForm.terminal}']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//option[@value='R']").click()
```

This is not an elegant way to handle this problem, but it is straightforward.